# How to solve $e^{ix}=i$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, exponential-function

This is a question related to another posted question:

The answer to the following question "Find all solutions to: $e^{ix}=i$" is as follows:

"Euler's formula: $e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$,

so: $ \cos x+i\sin x=0+1⋅i$

compare real and imaginary parts
$\sin(x)=1$
and
$\cos(x)=0$

$x=\frac{(4n+1)π}2$, $n∈$
(W stands for set of whole number W={0,1,2,3,.......,n})."

My question: Where does $x=\frac{(4n+1)π}2$, $n∈$ come from?

My steps:

1. $\cos(x) + i\sin(x) = 0 + i(1)$
2. $\cos(x) = i(1 - \sin(x))$
3. ...
4. how does $x=\frac{(4n+1)π}2$ follow?

Comment: I think you meant to write $e^{ix}$ instead of $e^{i^x}$.

Comment: Fixed that, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you copied the part about $W$ correctly? The set of whole numbers is not $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n\},$ it's $\{0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\dots\}.$ Anyway, the equation $e^{ix}=i$ does not have just $n+1$ solutions, it has an infinite number of solutions.

Comment: @bof _whole numbers_ is a vague term. When I was in high school, they were the counting numbers (nonnegative integers).

Comment: @SultanofSwing  *Whole* = *integer*. The term *integer* (or *whole number*) is not vague or ambiguous. Some people say "integer" when they mean "nonnegative integer", but they are just wrong.

Comment: @bof I can totally appreciate that that's how you learned it and that's the way you think of it. But the fact is that in most university-level mathematics texts, the definition of *whole numbers* is either different depending on the text, or not defined entirely. I have high school texts that say whole numbers "are the counting numbers 0, 1, 2, ...", and others that use *whole numbers* synonymously with *integers*. Other than that, I've never even seen *whole numbers* defined in uni-level texts. The clear fact remains: there is no right or wrong when it comes to ambiguous mathematical terms.

Comment: @bof refer to both http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whole+number and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WholeNumber.html. There are different definitions and ambiguities. Most would say that _whole numbers_ is loosely defined and not mathematically rigorous in the same sense that, say, the epsilon-delta definition of a limit is.

Answer (score 3):

$\sin$ and $\cos$ functions are $2\pi$-periodic which is: $\sin(x+2n\pi)=\sin x$, $\cos(x+2n\pi)=\cos(x)$. So when you find that $x=\pi/2$ is a solution, then also $x_n = \pi/2 + 2n\pi$ is a solution for every $n\in \mathbb Z$ (where $\mathbb Z$ are whole numbers: $0, 1, -1, 2, -2,\dots$)

Notice that
$$
  \frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi = \frac{4n+1}{2}\pi.
$$

Comment: That clears up things so well! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

I always find it easier to use a fixed method, and I thought you might find this explanation easier, so I'm posting it.

Start by putting everything into exponential form. Now $i = e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}}$. You can derive this from $e^{i\pi} = -1$ and taking square roots on both sides.

Now note that for *any* $\theta$, $e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2k\pi)}, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and this is because $e^{2k\pi i} = 1$. Essentially, this can be viewed as the periodicity of the exponential form. To compute general solutions or roots, you would be well-advised to include this term so that you don't miss any solutions.

Hence you can now write $i = e^{i(\frac{\pi}{2} + 2k\pi)} = e^{i\pi\frac{4k+1}{2}}$

Note that the final step is just an algebraic rearrangement of the exponent.

You can now immediately solve the equation by taking logs of both sides, i.e.

$e^{ix} = e^{i\pi\frac{4k+1}{2}}\\ \implies x = \pi\frac{4k+1}{2}$ which is essentially the required form.

Answer (score 0):

You said it, you compare real and imaginary parts. $\cos(x)=0$ and $\sin(x)=1$. When is this true?

Comment: cos(1)=0 and sin(0)=1 and I understand that one solution is $\frac{π}2$ but where does the $4n+1$ come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- $i$ is **a point on the unit circle**.
- $e^{ix}$ is *also* **a point on the unit circle**, lying *x* radians away from $(1,0)$, in trigonometric or counterclockwise direction.

So, to answer a question with a question, What is the position of $i$ on the unit circle, and How many radians away from $(1,0)$ does it lie, in trigonometric or counterclockwise direction ?

Comment: Also, remember that we are dealing with a circle, so if $x=a$ is *a* solution, then $x=a+k\cdot360^\circ=$ $=a+2k\pi$ is *also* a solution, for *all* $k\in\mathbb Z$.